# Is 'it' omittable?

Tags: grammar

My teacher sent me a Facebook friend request, and I accepted (it).

In the above, is 'it' omittable in informal writing?

Comment: Yes, you can omit *it* in informal writing. *It* (meaning the "Facebook request")  is implied by the first clause.

Comment: It is certainly understandable but I personally would always include "it"